# Is there an Android mail app that can store local copies of all my mail without being too slow?

Tags: android, email

I still often happen to be with no internet connection on or a severely metered data connection. For this reason,  I would like to have all my e-mail history (about 15 years and 13 GB worth of mail) stored on my phone. Is there an e-mail app that would be able to store all this on the phone itself (via IMAP) and would be fast? My mail client (M2 from Opera) was last updated seven years ago and can do that on my desktop, so I think it should be technically possible, but the only app that even seems to allow this, K9, was unbearably slow when I tried.

Comment: Hi. Also search here for potential answers: https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have tried K9 with much less data than that & am having problems. Sometimes some messages are not shown. Sometimes the app crashes. I really hope that you get a good answer :-)

Comment: @Z Z They did not like it there: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220966/which-mail-app-can-store-local-copies-of-all-my-mail-without-being-too-slow